# Calculator selection stays after submit

Tags: php, submit, calculator

Hello i'm trying to make a calculator.And i have this problem : I'm tryng to make the selection that i made it to stay after submit. I've found some code on google for my selection to stay after submit but my calculator won't work anymore. Can you help me ?

here is the code when my calculator works but my selection doesn"t stays after submit

```
<html>
 <body>
<center>
<form method="post">
    Food:
        <Select name="Dropdown"><br>
        <option>Cheese</option>
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Egg</option>
        </select>
       </br> 
    Amount:
        <input name="amount" type="text">grams<br><br>
        <br><input type="Submit" value="Calculate">  
        <br><br> 


        <?php
            $result=$_POST['result'];
                    $Dropdown=$_POST['Dropdown'];
                    $amount = $_POST['amount'];

                switch ($Dropdown){
                        case 'Cheese':
                        $result= (7.74  * $amount) / 100;
                        echo "<p> $result </p>";

                        break;
                        case 'Apple':
                        $result= (1.94  * $amount) / 100;
                        echo "<p> $result </p>";

                        break;
                         case 'Egg':
                        $result= (13.74  * $amount) / 100;
                        echo "<p> $result </p>";

                        }
                        ?> 
        </form> 
        </center> 
          </body>
</html>
```

and here is my code when my slection stays after submit but my calculator won't work

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['Dropdown'])) {
    $dropDownVal = $_POST['Dropdown'];
} else {
    $dropDownVal = 1;
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <select name="Dropdown" >
        <option value="1" <?php if ($dropDownVal==1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Cheese </option>
        <option value="2" <?php if ($dropDownVal==2) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Apple</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if ($dropDownVal==3) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Egg</option>
   </select>

   <?php
            $result=$_POST['result'];
            $Dropdown=$_POST['Dropdown'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];

                switch ($Dropdown){
                        case 'Cheese':
                        $result= (7.74  * $amount) / 100;
                        echo "<p> $result </p>";

                        break;
                        case 'Apple':
                        $result= (1.94  * $amount) / 100;
                        echo "<p> $result </p>";

                        break;
                         case 'Egg':
                        $result= (13.74  * $amount) / 100;
                        echo "<p> $result </p>";

                        }
                        ?> 



    <input name="amount" type="text">grams<br><br>
        <br><input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you receive back in the $_POST['Dropdown'] is the value not the content so you will get 1 or 2 or 3 and not the Cheese or Apple or Egg.

So try:

```
    switch ($Dropdown){
    case 1: // Cheese
         $result= (7.74  * $amount) / 100;
         break;
    case 2:  //Apple
         $result= (1.94  * $amount) / 100;
         break;
    case 3:  // Egg
         $result= (13.74  * $amount) / 100;
         break;
    default:
         $result = 0;
    }
    echo "<p> $result </p>";
?>
```

In future if you are not sure what is in a variable that is returned from the user do a

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $_POST, TRUE ) . '</pre>';
```

to get a nice display of the array on the browser.
Or a

```
var_dump( $var );
```